# Passing global variable from header.php to functions.php

Tags: functions, globals

Situation:

Is header.php file where is code: `if(is_single()){ global $my_global_var; $my_global_var == true; }`

Is functions.php file where is code: `global $my_global_var; if($my_global_var == true) { echo "OK"; }`

But this is not working, what im doing wrong?

In sidebar all is fine.

Fixed 0.2:
Must be:

```
    add_filter('the_content','simple_img_tag_search');
    function simple_img_tag_search($content){
    if(is_single()){
        $MYCODE = "<div>My code</div>";
        $paragraphs = explode( '</h2>', $content, 2 );
        $first_paragraph = $paragraphs[0];
        return str_replace($first_paragraph.'</h2>',$first_paragraph.'</h2>'.$MYCODE,$content);
    }}
```

Comment: It's not working because `functions.php` is loaded before `header.php`. By the time your header file sets it's variable, functions.php has already been executed.  You need to post your code -- including what you're trying to accomplish -- to get any more help that that. :)

Comment: @Vital You already got 7 questions here on the site. Please take your time, go back and edit your question with the WYSIWYG editor. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`is_single()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_single) is a function returning a `boolean` value. You could simply use it for your conditional check rather than passing the global variable.

Other than that, your first line of code should be setting `$my_global_var` with a single equal sign, i.e.: `$my_global_var = true;`.